# React not rendering component with URL param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm creating a website that will have the following:

1. A page that has a list of items.
2. A page that will show more details about an individual item

I'm using `react-router ^3.0.0`, `react-router-redux ^4.0.7`, and `webpack 2.1.0-beta.20` in the site. I'm trying to set up my routes like so:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import {combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {routerReducer, syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux';
import {IntlProvider, intlReducer} from 'react-intl-redux';
import {addLocaleData} from 'react-intl';
import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';

import {Home} from './app/components/Home/Home';
import Profile from './app/components/Profile/Profile';
import Login from './app/components/Login/Login';
import SignUp from './app/components/SignUp/SignUp';
import Items from './app/components/Items/Items';
import Item from './app/components/Item/Item';
import {requireAuthentication} from './app/components/General/AuthenticatedComponent';
import {reducers} from './app/reducers/reducers';
import {i18n} from './app/i18n/i18n';

import './index.scss';

addLocaleData([
    ...en
]);

// Create the store from the reducers
const store = createStore(combineReducers({
    reducers,
    routing: routerReducer,
    intl: intlReducer
}), i18n, applyMiddleware(thunk));

// Create an enhanced history that syncs navigation events with the store
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale="en" defaultLocale="en">
            <Router history={history}>
                <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/profile" component={requireAuthentication(Profile, true)}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={requireAuthentication(Login, false)}/>
                <Route path="/signup" component={requireAuthentication(SignUp, false)}/>

                {/* Items route lists all of the items, Item shows details for one individual item */}
                <Route path="/items" component={Items}/>
                <Route path="/items/:itemId" component={Item}/>
            </Router>
        </IntlProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The `Items` and `Item` components are unrelated, and do not depend on each other.

When I navigate to `http://localhost/items`, the `Items` component renders. But when I navigate to `http://localhost/items/1`, nothing renders, and I get the following error in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/items/index.js
```

I've tried to fix this a few ways, each resulting in the same error message

```
...
<Route path="/items" component={Items}/>
<Route path="/items/:itemId" component={Item}/>
...

...
<Route path="/items" component={Items}>
    <Route path="/:itemId" component={Item}/>
</Route>
...

...
<Route path="/items">
    <IndexRoute component={Items}/>
    <Route path="/:itemId" component={Item}/>
</Route>
...
```

I am able to get the `Item` component to render with the param when I do this though

```
...
// Navigate to http://localhost:3000/1
<Route path="/:itemId" component={Item}/>
...
```

But that's not how I want the URLs to be set up. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have `{this.props.children}` set in the `Items` component? Because `Item` is dependent on `Item` if that's not set `Item` will never render.

Comment: @KeithA, Doesn't that only matter if you nest them? (e.g. the 2nd/3rd attempts at it). I have tried putting `{this.props.children}` in `Items` with the same error. Besides, I don't want the `Item` component to render inside `Items` since they have completely different layouts.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that. Is this error `GET http://localhost:3000/items/index.js` the whole error? Do you mind posting the `Item` and `Items` components?

Comment: When I nest the routes, I get two `GET http://localhost:3000/items/index.js` errors (I only get 1 when I don't nest it). It links to the line in my `index.html` file where the `index.js` file is compiled and inserted (at the end of the `<body>` tag). That's the whole error, so I don't have much to go off of

Comment: Hmm, OK. Do you mind posting the `Item` and `Items` components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this was not a `react-router` problem, but instead a `webpack` problem. I took a look at the source code that was being compiled, and it looked like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,7s00" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://fountainjs.io/assets/imgs/fountain.png" />
        <title>My Web App</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Entry point for the application -->
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `index.js` file should be linked as `/index.js`, otherwise it looks in the current directory that the route is in. So in my `webpack.conf.js` file, I found a section that mentions `index.js`

```
output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
    filename: 'index.js'
}
```

I simply changed it to

```
output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
    filename: '/index.js'
}
```

And it worked. The `index.js` file is now linked properly in the source

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works, if you don't want to render `Item` inside `Items`

```js
<Route path="/items">
  <IndexRoute component={ Items } />
  <Route path=":itemId" component={ Item } />
</Route>
```

in `react-router`, if you put `/` in front of the path, it always becomes an absolute route (`example.org/:itemId`), and without the route is relative (`example.org/items/:itemId`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried this, and it didn't work. I'm still getting the same error

Comment: 1) Do you have a backend server running locally as well @TFischer, 2) Do these errors occur only when you try to navigate to the url from the browser address bar or also when clicking on a `Link` with the path?

Comment: Try this for me. Add a `<Link to="/items/1">Link</Link>` from `react-router` to your code and see it clicking that works.